# What is the reason for this contradiction about the size of the char type?

Tags: programming-languages, virtual-memory, bit-manipulation

the size of one char in C is 4 bytes, however to define an 'A' character we use the sum of two values like this expression here:

[image: Text]

or in other way i want to say that the char is 4 bytes size, but in the example it shows that the size is 8 bytes.

how it happens, what is wrong here ?

Comment: Size of char in C is 1 byte or 8 bits.

Comment: You can check the size of character data type in C using `sizeof(char)` which shall return the size of a data type in bytes. You shall get the answer as 1. The polynomial which you have written is nothing but the decimal conversion of the 8 bit binary number `01000001` which `65` in decimal and this happens to be the ASCII code of the character `A`

Comment: ASCII is a standard code for character representation, where the least significant 7 bits are used to represent character. giving a total of 128 characters while the most significant bit is used for parity...

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh Size of `char` in C is at least 8 bits.

Comment: With emphasis on _at least_ which means it can be more. Like 12, 16 or 32.

Comment: Abikesh, no, the eighth bit in ASCII _must_ be zero. Feel free to add a parity bit and call it “ASCII with parity”, but it’s not ASCII.

Comment: @pseudonym sorry about the size. Actually I have learnt about C from K&R 's C book, where on page 36, the authors say that `char` is a single byte... So from that I had made the comment. :( Thanks for the guidance anyways

Comment: @gnasher729 ok. Actually in most places it is said that since char uses 8 bits and ASCII uses 7 bits, we are free to use the most significant bit for parity. The value printed remains the same using "%c" whether there is a 1 or 0 in the msb of the 8 bits of character variable... Thanks for pointing it out and helping me. Actually what I wrote previously seems a bit fuzzy and it appears that ASCII is of 8 bits, which is not ...

Answer (score 1):

Sizeof(char) = sizeof(unsigned char) = sizeof(signed char) = 1 by definition in C and C++. And char contains at least 8 bit (it can be more, but 8 is by far the most common).

So your assumption that the size of one char in C is 4 is wrong. However, in C a character literal like 'x' has type int, not type char, so sizeof('x') = sizeof(int) is usually larger than 1, and 4 is not unusual but in no way guaranteed.

Your calculation doesn’t show that sizeof(char) would be 8 in any way, because you confused “bit” and “byte”.